# Convert the output of for loop of JSON in string

Tags: javascript, json

How can I combine the output data and make it a string, from a for loop in Javascript.

Here's my snippet.

```
for (let index = 0; index < routes.length; index++) {
     let element = routes[index];
     meSpeak.speak(element.narrative, speakConfig);
}
```

It results,

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

I want to make it as a one String only. like this

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

Comment: Why not use `routes.join(' ')`?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: share sample data ? or live demo ? what is `routes` and what does `meSpeak.speak()` ?

Comment: `routes.forEach(element => meSpeak.speak(element.narrative, speakConfig).join(' ');` should work

Comment: in the routes array, there is a narrative index, i got the data from the routes[index].narrative, and i want to is to make it as a single string

Comment: Did you try my demo, and see if it will fit your need or at least fit it according to your context which is at this point limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `join()`

```
const routes = [{'narrative':'word 1'},{'narrative':'word2'},
{'narrative':'word 3'},{'narrative':'word 4'}];
let out = []

routes.map((el)=>(out.push(el.narrative)));
res = out.join(' ');
```

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vt4zd8ck/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using array. I have sample codes here. Try to implement the logic in your problem

```
var apples = ["Apple1", "Apple2", "Apple3", "Apple4"];
fruits.toString();
```

The result will be like:

```
Apple1,Apple2,Apple3,Apple4
```

Comment: `apples` != `fruits`  and output should like `Apple1 Apple2` not `Apple1,Apple2`

Answer (score 0):

You could add the strings to a variable outside of the for loop and then "speak" the string when the for loop is done.

```
s = ""
for (let index = 0; index < routes.length; index++) {
     s += str(routes[index].narrative)
}
meSpeak.speak(s, speakConfig);
```